# WKWebView UITableView Cell Height and Instagram Embed Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, instagram, wkwebview

I'm trying to add Instagram posts to cells in a table view, but I can't get the cell height calculation right despite trying a bunch of different things. I'm creating a `WKWebView` for each cell and using `loadHTMLString` with the embed code supplied by Instagram, with one slight modification to Instagram's HTML which is this:

```
`<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"></head>`
```

When I run it in the simulator, the Instagram post appears to be the right size for about half a second, then it gets resized.

Below is some basic code that demonstrates the problem when run, with a single hardcoded Instagram post displayed in two different cells for example purposes. If I use `loadRequest` and a `NSURLRequest` with a random website instead of `loadHTMLString` the cells are sized fine and it all works as expected. How can I use Instagram embed codes in UITableViewCells in a way that the entire post is shown?

**InstagramViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface InstagramViewController : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**InstagramViewController.m**

```
#import "InstagramViewController.h"

@interface InstagramViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL loaded;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat cellHeight;

@end

@implementation InstagramViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"simpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [webView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    webView.tag = indexPath.section;
    NSString *instagramEmbedHTML = @"\
    <!DOCTYPE html>\
    <html>\
    <head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\
    </head>\
    <body>\
    <blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version=\"7\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\">\
    <div style=\"padding:8px;\">\
    <div style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:41.91489361702128% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\">\
    <div style=\" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\">\
    </div>\
    </div>\
    <p style=\" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;\">\
    <a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/BVR2uajF1Qc/\" style=\" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;\" target=\"_blank\">I wish for... free cupcakes!!  First 50 customers at our #Gramercy location get a free #Summer Collection 3-Pack to celebrate 5 beautiful, magical years on 23rd St!  Today only! Open &#39;til 10pm  #happybirthday</a>\
    </p>\
    <p style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\">A post shared by Baked by Melissa (@bakedbymelissa) on <time style=\" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;\" datetime=\"2017-06-13T12:00:48+00:00\">Jun 13, 2017 at 5:00am PDT</time>\
    </p>\
    </div>\
    </blockquote>\
    <script async defer src=\"http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"></script>\
    </body></html>";
    [webView loadHTMLString:instagramEmbedHTML baseURL:nil];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:webView];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self calculateHeightForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(CGFloat)calculateHeightForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexP{
    while (!_loaded) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
    NSLog(@"new cell height: %f", _cellHeight);
    return _cellHeight;
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSLog(@"I finished");
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.scrollHeight;" completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        }
        NSLog(@"new scrollHeight Result %@",result);
        float ht = [result floatValue];
        NSIndexPath* indexOfCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:webView.tag];
        UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexOfCell];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, ht);
        _cellHeight = ht;
        self.loaded = YES;
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

Here's a screenshot of the output I get when I run the above code in which you can see the size of the embed exceeds the size of the calculated cell height, cutting off the entire comment section in this case:

[image: The author's text for each Instagram post is cut off because of the sizing issue]

Comment: bad idea to load web view in UITableView

Comment: I've read that too many web views in a table would tax memory. I'd imagine table scroll responsiveness could also be tricky. Are there other reasons to avoid this? What's the alternative, asynchronously loading images and constructing my own cell that conforms to Instagram's terms of use?

Comment: The table view cells are reusable, so your content would load again and again during scrolling and reusing. Furthermore, you display the active content in a cell. And the user can tap "follow" and other active elements. This would lead to opening a new page in a cell, and i think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this for a very long time. This solution works for me.

You will get the appropriate height. From that point it is your task to handle it and set the container's height.

BE WARNED: It was not straightforward.

NOTE: Instagram and Twitter embed is a really awful animal here. Their script calculates the height for the width ot 621(!) and sets it as the attribute of the iframe. So you "simply" (LOL) have to recalculate the size. See the new attribute "modded", to avoid setting height multiple times.

NO CROSS DOMAIN restrictions. You cannot read/alter an iframe's content loaded from an url different from the baseURL-s domain. That would be too easy, but browsers deny this for a very good reason.

This is a mixed solution using HTML, CSS, Javascript and of course Swift.

```
func initMyWebView() {

//...

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences = preferences
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        config.userContentController = contentController
        config.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

        contentController.add(
            self,
            name: "heightChanged"
        )
        contentController.add(
            self,
            name: "log"
        )
        contentController.removeAllUserScripts()
        contentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: windowSizeWatcherScript(), injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))
// ...

}

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "log" {
            print("JSLog: " + String(describing: message.body))
            return
        }

        if message.name == "heightChanged" {
            if let messageDict = message.body as? Dictionary<String, CGFloat> {
                if nil != messageDict["height"] {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        // Implement the height update to your needs
                        self?.updateHeight(height: messageDict["height"]!)
                    }
                }
            }
            return
        }

    }


func style(jsonStyle: JSONTextStyleModel?) -> String {
        let maxHTMLW = bounds.width

        return """
        html, body {
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: \(maxHTMLW)px !important;
            min-width: \(maxHTMLW)px !important;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Roboto;
            background-color: \(Theme.shared.generalColors.background);
            color: \((jsonStyle?.color).defaultsTo(value: "#333"));
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        #\(contentId) {
            margin: 0 2% !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            width: 96%;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        iframe.instagram-media-rendered {
        }
        """
    }

    func online(html: String, with style: String) -> String {
        return """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <style>
                \(style)
                </style>                
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="\(contentId)">
                    \(html)
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        """
    }

 func windowSizeWatcherScript() -> String {
        let maxInstaW = bounds.width * 0.96
        return """
            var prevHeight = 0;
            var prevWidth = 0;
            var contentId = "\(contentId)";
            customLog("windowSizeWatcherScript added")

            var resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function () { resize(); }, 125);


            if (typeof(webkit) !== 'undefined' && typeof(webkit.messageHandlers.log) !== 'undefined') {
                console.log = customLog;
            }

            function resize() {
                clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout('resize();', 250);

                if (typeof(webkit) == 'undefined' || typeof(webkit.messageHandlers.heightChanged) == 'undefined') {
                    customLog("Cannot send webkit messages");
                    return;
                }


                if (resizeInsta()) {
                    return
                }

                if (resizeTwitter()) {
                    return
                }

                if (resizeIframes()) {
                    return
                }

                if (resizeContent()) {
                    return
                }

                resizeDocument()

            }

            function customLog(message) {
                if (typeof(webkit) == "undefined" || typeof(webkit.messageHandlers.log) == "undefined") {
                    console.log("No native app context");
                    console.log(message)
                    return
                }
                try { webkit.messageHandlers.log.postMessage(message);} catch (err) { console.log("No native app context"); }
            }

            function handleSize(width, height) {
                if (height > 0 && prevHeight != height) {
                    customLog("W: " + width + " H: " + height);
                    try { webkit.messageHandlers.heightChanged.postMessage({"height": height});} catch (err) { customLog("No native app context"); }
                    customLog("Detected width " + width + " and height " + height);
                    prevHeight = height;
                }
            }

            function resizeInsta() {
                var insta = document.getElementsByClassName("instagram-media-rendered");

                if (typeof(insta) !== "undefined" && insta.length > 0) {
                    var width = insta[0].offsetWidth;
                    var height = Math.max(insta[0].scrollHeight, insta[0].offsetHeight);
                    var h = insta[0].getAttribute("height")
                    if (h !== "undefined" && h > 0) {
                        var modded = insta[0].getAttribute("modded")
                        if (modded == "undefined") {
                            h = h.replace("px", "")
                            let r = \(maxInstaW) / 621;
                            height = h * r;
                            width = \(Int(maxInstaW));
                            insta[0].setAttribute("height", height + "px");
                            insta[0].setAttribute("modded", "1");
                            insta[0].setAttribute("width", "\(Int(maxInstaW))px");
                        }
                    }
                    handleSize(width, height)
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            function resizeTwitter() {
                var insta = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-tweet-rendered");

                if (typeof(insta) !== "undefined" && insta.length > 0) {
                    var width = insta[0].offsetWidth;
                    var height = Math.max(insta[0].scrollHeight, insta[0].offsetHeight);
                    var h = insta[0].getAttribute("height")
                    if (h !== "undefined" && h > 0) {
                        var modded = insta[0].getAttribute("modded")
                        if (modded == "undefined") {
                            h = h.replace("px", "")
                            let r = \(maxInstaW) / 621;
                            height = h * r;
                            width = \(Int(maxInstaW));
                            insta[0].setAttribute("height", height + "px");
                            insta[0].setAttribute("modded", "1");
                            insta[0].setAttribute("width", "\(Int(maxInstaW))px");
                        }
                    }
                    handleSize(width, height)
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            function resizeIframes() {
                var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

                if (typeof(iframes) !== "undefined" && iframes.length > 0) {
                    var width = iframes[0].offsetWidth;
                    var height = Math.max(iframes[0].scrollHeight, iframes[0].offsetHeight);
                    handleSize(width, height)
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }

            function resizeContent() {
                var content = document.getElementById(contentId);
                if (typeof(content) !== 'undefined') {
                        var width = content.offsetWidth;
                        var height = Math.max(content.scrollHeight, content.offsetHeight);
                        handleSize(width, height)
                        return true
                }
                return false
            }

        function resizeDocument() {
            var width = document.body.offsetWidth;
            var height = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
            handleSize(width, height)
            return true
        }
"""
    }
```